# Duplicating the lines apart from the header row

Tags: text-formatting

How can I duplicate all but the first line in a file?

Example:

```
Id_animal Id_SNP Allele
ID01 rs01 AB
ID02 rs01 BA
ID03 rs01 AA
ID04 rs01 BB
```

Desired output:

```
Id_animal Id_SNP Allele
ID01 rs01 AB
ID01 rs01 AB
ID02 rs01 BA
ID02 rs01 BA
ID03 rs01 AA
ID03 rs01 AA
ID04 rs01 BB
ID04 rs01 BB
```

My real file has `400` lines and `44709376` column. So I want an output with `799` lines and `44709376` columns.

Comment: "Re: marked as dupe": None of the answers in the thread this one is marked as duplicate of contain any mention, how OP (or similar skill-level target audience) could insert a conditional deciding whether the first line should be skipped in the duplication.

Answer (score 3):

Use specialized tools like `awk`:

```
awk '1;NR>1' < input.file
```

this is a shorthand for `awk 'true {print $0}; NR>1 {print $0}'`

or `sed`:

```
sed '1!p' < input.file
```

`sed` -by default- outputs every input line. `'1!p'` means "All but the first line: Print again"